# debugging django signals' problems

Tags: django, django-signals, django-registration

I'm having problems with connecting to a signal in django. I've been following a tutorial available at http://dmitko.ru/?p=546 and tried to extend user registration.

I have django-registration correctly set up. It is working fine. For debug purpose I've put the following code into my urls.py:

```
from registration.signals import user_registered

def log_user_created(sender, user, request, ** kwargs):
  logger.debug("got USER_REGISTERED signal")

if settings.DEBUG:
  logger.debug("registering debug signal listeners")
  user_registered.connect(log_user_created)
else:
  logger.debug("debuging signals not enabled")
```

However the log_user_created function is never called.

**My question is:** how can I debug my app to see where the user_registered signal is being swallowed?

Note: I've checked that my version of django-registration works correctly. I've switched my version with the one from the mentioned blog's example app. It did not change the observed behaviour.

Comment: You can check the [following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392042/why-does-the-signal-not-trigger/40400653#40400653).

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the code that connects to the signal and the code that sends signals both import the with the same path. For example, if you connect a signal with:

```
from myapp.registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(...)
```

Then later when you send this signal you *must* import it with

```
from myapp.registration.signals import user_registered
```

(notice the **myapp.**) and *not*:

```
from registration.signals import user_registered
```

otherwise they'll be treated as two different signals.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put `user_registered.connect(user_created)` in `regbackend.py` (and not in urls.py) as shown in the example you linked?

You can find some additional info on where to best connect your signals in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719038/where-should-signal-handlers-live-in-a-django-project).

To see if `user_registered` is called correctly you simply could add a debug call at the beginning of the `user_created` function.

[django-debug-toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar), though i haven't used that specific feature, might be another  option:

> Currently, the following panels have
>   been written and are working:
>
> - List of signals, their args and receivers

Comment: The mentioned steps are what I've already done. Neither debug log at the beginning of my __user_registered__ function, nor placing it in regbackend.py helped. I've also used django-debug-toolbar, but it doesn't show the user_registered signal. Not in my app, and not in the working on, (http://dmitko.ru/?p=546)

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample application, that you can play with (I believe it works)
http://dmitko.ru/samples/sample_user_registration.zip

Comment: I've tried it, but as I've written in my question, it works great. I can't figure out how to debug my app. I'm pretty sure I did all the things that You did in your app (apparently I'm wrong as my app is not working ;-) ). I've included django-debug-toolbar but it does not show __user_registered__ signal, neither in my app nor in yours. Do you know how to debug the problem with sending the signals in django?