# Why does the signal not trigger?

Tags: django, signals, django-registration, django-signals

Sitting over a day on it. Really can't understand why this signal is not triggered when a user is activated, no error log, no exception in the admin on activation. Can anybody help? The following code should result in a log message in the apache error.log when a user, right?

```
import logging
from django.dispatch import receiver
from registration.signals import user_activated

@receiver(user_activated)
def registered_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    logger = logging.getLogger("user-activated")
    logger.error("activated here")
```

same with `user_registered`

Answer (score 3):

First of all im using **django 1.8.3** .You should register your signal first. As far as i know, there are some methods to do that but this is what im doing;
Create `signals.py`  in your app write your signal there;

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
@receiver(post_save, sender=your_model,dispatch_uid="yourmodel_save_receiver")
            def post_save_yourmodel(sender, instance, **kwargs):
                 if instance.profile_status:
                     print "active"
                 else:
                     print "not active"
```

Then you should create `apps.py`. This file contains configuration information to your model.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class yourmodel_config(AppConfig):
    name = 'yourmodel_config'
    verbose_name = 'your_model config'

    def ready(self):
        import yourmodel.signals
```

With this whenever your app is ready, your signals will be imported
Finally open your `__init__.py` and add the following.

```
default_app_config = 'yourmodel.apps.yourmodel_config'
```

With this you are defining application configuration for your model.This example when ever `yourmodel` is saved, signal checks for `profile_status` attribute and prints output depending on the value(true or false) to your console. You can also add `created` parameter to your model to know that if instance of the model is created. `created` will return True if a new record was created. `def post_save_yourmodel(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):`. Otherwise this signal will be triggered whenever your model is saved with `yourmodel.save()`.
**Consider that is a `post_save` example.You can find list of the model signals from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals).**

Comment: If I understand correctly you describe how to make new signals right? I'm using a predefined one, though. And if I'm not doing something wrong there is a bug in that framework I'm using (django-registration, or the templates I'm using for them). So, the question is more like "do you see a spelling error or do you also think this is a bug?"

Comment: Yes, this is how you can implement new signals. I dont think that your problem is a bug. You have to sign your receiver to app somehow like this post_save.connect(registered_callback,sender=mymodel). Maybe this is why your receiver didnt catch any signals but i have no experience with your method so im not quite sure whats your problem is.

Comment: Well, how would you interpret the [registration documentation](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/signals.html)? I would say they are quite confident about having already implemented the signals. And one of them even works, as long as I don't register to the second. I don't think adding a receive should remove or side-effect to not triggering another.