# The right place to keep my signals.py file in a Django project

Tags: django, django-signals

Based on Django's documentation I was reading, it seems like `signals.py` in the app folder is a good place to start with, but the problem I'm facing is that when I create signals for `pre_save` and I try to import the class from model it conflicts with the `import` in my model.

```
# models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from signals import *

class Comm_Queue(CommunicatorAbstract):
    queue_statuses = (
        ('P', _('Pending')),
        ('S', _('Sent')),
        ('E', _('Error')),
        ('R', _('Rejected')),
    )
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_index=True, default='P')
    is_html         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language        = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=settings.LANGUAGES)
    sender_email    = models.EmailField()
    recipient_email = models.EmailField()
    subject         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content         = models.TextField()
```

---

```
# signals.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from models import Comm_Queue

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Comm_Queue)
def get_sender_email_from_settings(sender, **kwargs):
    obj=kwargs['instance']
    if not obj.sender_email:
        obj.sender_email='%s' % settings.ADMINS[0][1]
```

This code will not run because I import `Comm_Queue` inside `signals.py` and I also import the signals inside `models.py`.

Can anyone advice on how I could over come this issue?

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should signal handlers live in a django project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719038/where-should-signal-handlers-live-in-a-django-project)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

#### Original answer, for Django < 1.7:

You can register the signals by importing `signals.py` in the app's `__init__.py` file:

```
# __init__.py
import signals
```

This will allow to import `models.py` from `signals.py` without circular import errors.

One problem with this approach is that it messes up the coverage results if you're using coverage.py.

[Related discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/PReHoxwwG_c/M-asj72ks7YJ)

#### Edit: For Django >= 1.7:

Since AppConfig was introduced, the recommended way of importing signals is in its `init()` function. See  [Eric Marcos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21612050/543561) for more details.

Comment: using signals in Django 1.9, use below method(recommanded by django). this method doesn't work giving `AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")`

Comment: Eric Marcos his answer should be the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21612050/3202958 since Django >= 1.7, using the app config

Comment: Agreed. I'll edit the answer to point to Eric Marcos's answer for Django 1.7+

Answer (score 231):

If you're using Django<=1.6 I'd recommend Kamagatos solution: just import your signals at the end of your models module.

For future versions of Django (>=1.7), the [recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) way is to import your signals module in your app's config [ready()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) function:

`my_app/apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        import my_app.signals
```

`my_app/__init__.py`

```
default_app_config = 'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Comment: They also mention in the 1.7 documentation that sometimes ready can be called multiple times and so to avoid duplicate signals, attach a unique identifier to your signal connector call:

    request_finished.connect(my_callback, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")

Where dispatch_uid is usually a string but can be any hashable object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Accepted answer above throws an error when deploying using uwsgi

Comment: Hm, doesnt work for me with django 2. If i import model directly in ready - all fine. If i import model in signals and import signals in ready i'm getting a error `doesn't declare an explicit app_label` ..

Comment: @Aldarun you can try to put 'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig' inside INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 27):

To solve your problem you just have to import signals.py after your model definition. That's all.

Comment: This is by far the easiest, and I had no idea this would work without a cyclic dependency. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant. Like this one better than my answer.

Although I don't really understand how come it doesn't cause a circular import...

Comment: solution doesn't work with enabled autopep8 plugin in Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

I also put signals in signals.py file and also have this code snippet that loads all signals:

```
# import this in url.py file !

import logging

from importlib import import_module

from django.conf import settings

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

signal_modules = {}

for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    signals_module = '%s.signals' % app
    try:
        logger.debug('loading "%s" ..' % signals_module)
        signal_modules[app] = import_module(signals_module)
    except ImportError as e:
        logger.warning(
            'failed to import "%s", reason: %s' % (signals_module, str(e)))
```

This is for project, I'm not sure if it works at app level.

Comment: This is my favourite solution so far as it fits the other patterns (like tasks.py)

Comment: Found an issue with this one, if you start shell the urls.py doesn't get imported and your signals won't attach

Comment: yes, my answer is kind of outdated, it seems that django has AppConfig class these days. Last time I've used django it was version 1.3. Suggesting to investigate around it.

Comment: we are still 1.6 and so i had to move all our signals.py into models otherwise celery and management commands didn't get picked up

Answer (score 6):

In old Django versions would be fine to put the signals on the `__init__.py` or maybe in the `models.py`(although at the end models will be way to large for my taste).

With Django 1.9, it is better I think, to place the signals on a `signals.py` file and import them with the `apps.py`, where they are going to be loaded after loading the model.

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'polls'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals  # NOQA
```

You can also divide your signals on `signals.py` and `handlers.py` in another folder within your model named `signals` as well, but for me that is just over engineering. Take a look at [Placing Signals](https://chriskief.com/2014/02/28/django-1-7-signals-appconfig/)

Answer (score 6):

*This only applies if you have your signals in a separate `signals.py` file*

In completely agree with the answer of @EricMarcos but it should be stated that the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#for-application-users) explicitly advice not to use the default_app_config variable (although it is not wrong). **For current versions, correct way would be:**

**my_app/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        import my_app.signals
```

**settings.py**

(Make sure you don't just have your app name in installed apps but instead the relative path to your AppConfig)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig',
    # ...
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that you're doing that so your signals are registered, so that they're found somewhere. I just put my signals right in a models.py file normally.

Comment: yeah when I move the signal inside the model file it solves the problem. But my model.py file is pretty large with all the classes, managers and model rules.

Comment: Managers are a bit easer to pull out in my experience. Managers.py ftw.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to import the callback functions from `signals.py` and connect them in `models.py`:

signals.py

```
def pre_save_callback_function(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff here
```

model.py

```
# Your imports here
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from yourapp.signals import pre_save_callback_function

class YourModel:
    # Model stuff here
pre_save.connect(pre_save_callback_function, sender=YourModel)
```

Ps: Importing `YourModel` in `signals.py` will create a recursion; use `sender`, instead.

Ps2: Saving the instance again in the callback function will create a recursion. You can make a control argument in `.save` method to control it.