# Where to put django signal receiver code?

Tags: django

Hi I am defining my own signal and receiver. I just want to know where I should place my codes. It is in models.py or in views.py. Please help

Comment: Mostly in `models.py`, but if you want you can put that in separate file like `signal_handlers.py`

Comment: I was able to find out. I Placed my objects in models.py and imported them in views where I used the sender function

Comment: You Know I tried defining my own sigs.py but the function call was not working. Can U help me out. i would really like to tidy up my code

Comment: Could you update your question with relevant error details.

Comment: I created the signals_handlers.py and it works fine. thanks

Comment: Hmmm, that happened 2nd time with me today!

Comment: I usually put the hooks - i.e. `post_save.connect(...)` - in my `models.py` and the handlers themselves in a separate `signals.py` file. That way they are separate, imported automatically and don't clog up your models with extra code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should signal handlers live in a django project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719038/where-should-signal-handlers-live-in-a-django-project)

Comment: this question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115097/the-right-place-to-keep-my-signals-py-files-in-django

Answer (score 4):

Put your signal function into `signals.py` and
don't forget to put the app config in the `__init__.py` file and also 
ready method in the `apps.py` file.

`apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppNameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_name'

    def ready(self):
        import app_name.signals
```

`__init__.py` (app folder):

```
default_app_config = 'app_name.apps.AppNameConfig'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create python file - `signals.py` in your application.
2. Add this line in `__init__.py` in your application.

   `import signals`
3. Restart django project.

Work it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create `signals.py` file. But can not add `import signals` to `__init__.py` file. Because signal related models will not be loaded yet. So, in apps.py file you can find class which inherit from `AppConfig` class and this class has method `ready(self)` method. You should import your signals in this function:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MainConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'main'

    def ready(self):
        import main.signals
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an app called "app" to handle the pre_save signal of a model called "Model"

apps.py

```
from django import apps
from django.db.models import signals
class AppConfig(apps.AppConfig):
    name = 'app'
    def ready(self):
        # import here to avoid circular imports
        from app import signals as app_signals
        signals.pre_save.connect(app_signals.model_pre_save, sender=self.get_model('Model'))
```

signals.py

```
def model_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('raw', False):
        return  # raw implies fixture, ignore
    # add code here to handle signal
```