# How to extend the user model in django 1.9?

Tags: python, django

I've been searching around trying to figure this out, I want to add simple things to my `Profile` model like avatar, contact info, etc. However when following tutorials that I found online on how to do this, I am only met with errors.

This is what my model looks like (tracks/models.py):

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

...

class Profile(models.Model):

    def generate_user_folder_avatar(instance, filename):
        return "uploads/users/%s/%s.png" % (instance.user, 'avatar')

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_user_folder_avatar,validators=[is_square_png])

    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

I've set the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'tracks.Profile'` in settings.py but when I run my server I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'post_save' is not defined
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? I'm using Django 1.9 and Python 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NameError: name 'post_save' is not defined
```

you should do the import:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
```

*note #1*: you may be interested in the fact that Django provides more explicit and clear way to extend **User** model:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user

*note #2*: you probably want to connect signals not somewhere in models, but like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21612050/699864

Comment: Actually, the next answer is more apt: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21612050/1628832 for point #2

Comment: @karthikr ty! replaced the link for the note #2.