# Django: Programmatically add Groups on User save

Tags: python, django-models, django-users, django-related-manager

After a user is saved, I need to make sure that its instance is associated with a group by default.

I have found two ways to achieve that:

- Overriding the model's `save()` method

  models.py:

  ```
  from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Group


  class Person(AbstractUser):

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().save(*args, **kwargs)
          to_add = Group.objects.get(id=1)  # get_or_create is a better option
          instance.groups.add(to_add)
  ```
- Capturing a post_save signal:

  signals.py:

  ```
  from django.conf import settings
  from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
  from django.db.models.signals import post_save
  from django.dispatch import receiver


  @receiver(
      post_save,
      sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
  )
  def save_the_group(instance, raw, **kwargs):
      if not raw:
          to_add = Group.objects.get(id=1)  # get_or_create is a better option
          instance.groups.add(to_add)
  ```

Are these methods equal in achieving their goal?

Is there a better one in Django terms of "Good Practice"?

Comment: Sometimes it's easy for a few essential not very complicated bits to put it on the model, other times, the `signal` can go out to lots of things that want to register their interest in it, and work on it (though that's more likely for `pre_save` stuff and `post_save` stuff more likely for more signals :)... so extending apps etc... What's preferred is mostly (from my understanding) dependant on the environment and needs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**

Acquiring a better understanding of how Django works, I see that the
confusion and also the solution lie in [`BaseModelForm.save()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f1374f34da90e1d16e272c89ac07786e907e3778/django/forms/models.py#L456-L459):

```
    ...
    if commit:
        # If committing, save the instance and the m2m data immediately.
        self.instance.save()
        self._save_m2m()
    ...
```

and in [`BaseModelForm._save_m2m()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f1374f34da90e1d16e272c89ac07786e907e3778/django/forms/models.py#L440-L441):

```
    ...
    if f.name in cleaned_data:
        f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
    ...
```

The instance is first saved to acquire a primary key (`post_save`
signal emmited) and then all its many to many relations are saved based
on `ModelForm.cleaned_data`.

If any m2m relation has been added during the `post_save` signal or at
the `Model.save()` method, it will be removed or overridden from
`BaseModelForm._save_m2m()`, depending on the content of  the
`ModelForm.cleaned_data`.

The `transaction.on_commit()` -which is discussed as a solution in this
asnwer later on and in a few other SO answers from which I was inspired
and got downvoted- will delay the changes in the signal until
`BaseModelForm._save_m2m()` has concluded its operations.

Although, in some special cases the `transaction.on_commit()` [is very useful](https://ken-dev.info/django-tricks/2019/10/04/django-signals-in-transaction.html), in this case is an overkill, not only because it is complexing the situation in
an awkward manner (the most suitable signal is `m2m_changed` [as explained here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30022#comment:4)) but because avoiding signals altogether, is rather
[good](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/).

Therefore, I will try to give a solution that caters for both occasions:

1. If the instance is saved from Django Admin (ModelForm)
2. If the instance is saved without using a ModelForm

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Group


class Person(AbstractUser):
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not getattr(self, 'from_modelform', False):  # This flag is created in ModelForm
            <add - remove groups logic>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from my_app.models import Person


class PersonChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if self.errors:
            return
        group = cleaned_data['groups']
        to_add = Group.objects.filter(id=1)
        to_remove = Group.objects.filter(id=2)
        cleaned_data['groups'] = group.union(to_add).difference(to_remove)
        self.instance.from_modelform = True
        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

This will either work with:

```
>>> p = Person()
>>> p.username = 'username'
>>> p.password = 'password'
>>> p.save()
```

or with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory

user_creationform_data = {
    'username': 'george',
    'password1': '123!trettb',
    'password2': '123!trettb',
    'email': 'email@yo.gr',
}

user_model_form = modelform_factory(
    get_user_model(),
    form=UserCreationForm,
)
user_creation_form = user_model_form(data=user_creationform_data)
new_user = user_creation_form.save()
```

---

**Old answer**

Based on either [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23795811/2996101) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180727/trigering-post-save-signal-only-after-transaction-has-completed) SO questions along with an
article titled "[How to add ManytoMany model inside a post_save
signal](http://dayo.com.ng/django-add-manytomany-model-inside-post_save-signal/)" the solution I turned to, is to use [`on_commit(func, using=None)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit):

> The function you pass in will be called immediately after a
> hypothetical database write made where on_commit() is called would be
> successfully committed.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


def on_transaction_commit(func):
    ''' Create the decorator '''
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        transaction.on_commit(lambda: func(*args, **kwargs))

    return inner


@receiver(
    post_save,
    sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
)
@on_transaction_commit
def group_delegation(instance, raw, **kwargs):
        to_add = Group.objects.get(id=1)
        instance.groups.add(to_add)
```

The above code does not take into account that [every login causes a
post_save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35542890/2996101).

### Digging Deeper

A crucial point made in the relevant [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30022#comment:1) is that the
above code **will not work** if a `save()` call is made inside an
atomic transaction together with a validation that depends on the
result of the `group_delegation()` function.

```
@transaction.atomic
def accept_group_invite(request, group_id):
    validate_and_add_to_group(request.user, group_id)
    # The below line would always fail in your case because the
```

on_commit
# receiver wouldn't be called until exiting this function.
if request.user.has_perm('group_permission'):
do_something()
...

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#timing-of-execution) describe in more details the constraints under which
`on_commit()` successfully works.

### Testing

[During testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#use-in-tests), it is crucial to use the
[TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase) or the
[`@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)`](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html?highlight=request%20database#pytest-mark-django-db-request-database-access) decorator when testing with pytest.

[This](https://github.com/raratiru/django-testing-on-commit/blob/master/user/test_user.py) is an example of how I tested this signal.