# django signals do not send mail

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a blog and I want to send e-mail my subscribes when I published new post. I used django signals. My problem is that signal is not working. I can send mail when I try django shell.

This is my **signals.py** file :

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from blog.models import Blog
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Blog)
def new_post_created(sender,**kwargs)
    print "Success"
    mysubject = "E mail gönderiyorum"
    mymessage = "Merhaba, \nYeni yazım az önce yayınlandı. Hemen okumak için linki kullanabilirsin.\n http://www.cemreacar.com/blog/"
    mymail = "mail@cemreacar.com"
    send_mail(mysubject,mymessage,mymail,['*****@gmail.com'],'fail_silently=False')
```

Comment: Does your console print "Success"?

Comment: have you fill apps.py and import your signals file in AppModel like in that post?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56134874/8548036

Comment: @ncopiy When I try , settings.py throw error.

Comment: @cmracar which error? show the trace

Comment: @ncopiy Exception in thread django-main-thread:

...
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 93, in populate
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: blog

Comment: @cmracar okey, now please show me full apps.py file in application where your signal receiver lives

Comment: @Hybrid No , there is no success message.

Comment: @ncopiy  
from django.apps import AppConfig

class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'

    def ready(self):
        import blog.signals

Comment: @cmracar i guess somewhere in your apps there is another `AppConfig` with name 'blog'. try to use another one name (with settings.INSTALLED_APPS fix too)

Comment: @ncopiy Should I add like this ;
class EmailBlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'

    def ready(self):
        import blog.signals

Comment: @cmracar yes but check: name field must contains string with current application name. If your apps.py path is: `email_blog/apps.py` i means your `EmailBlogConfig` `name` field must be `"emails_blog"`

Comment: @ncopiy but , in this state , I will need to create new app , I do not want to this. why this is so confused?

Answer (score 0):

Have you overridden ready method? If not you have to override ready method of application configuration class.

In apps.py application configuration class will be defined. Override ready method as follows

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'your_app'

    def ready(self):
        import your_app.signal
```

In project settings.py update installed apps as follows:

Replace

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    '...',
    'your_app',
)
```

with

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    '...',
    'your_app.apps.YourAppConfig',
)
```

Documentation link - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready