# How I can make notification system in Django by signals

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How I can make a notification system in Django by signals, in which any user add like to the video send a notification to the author who added like to his video,
I tried everything and no thing worked with me

my model

```
class Video(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='post-videos', validators=[validate_file_extension])
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Account, blank=True, related_name='likes', default=None)
```

the signals file

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=Video.likes)
def update_likes(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created == False:
        instance.video.likes.save()
        print('like updated!')

post_save.connect(update_likes, sender=Video)
```

the notification model that I tried to base on my notification but I filed then I try by signals

```
class Notification(models.Model):
NOTIFICATION_TYPE = ((1, 'like'))

video = models.ForeignKey("videos.Video", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_video", blank=True, null=True)
sender = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_from_user")
user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_to_user")
notification_type = models.IntegerField(choices=NOTIFICATION_TYPE)
text_preview = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
is_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using signals.py file?
is the file imported?
try to move you post_save to models.py file... signals.py file needs to be imported as

[The right place to keep my signals.py file in a Django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115097/the-right-place-to-keep-my-signals-py-file-in-a-django-project)

django doesnt handle signals.py file... and if its not imported.. it doesnt run during startup