# Update Django model object once Celery task is complete

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I would like to update my model object once a celery task has completed.  I am currently at a loss about how to go about doing this though.

Here is a layout of the files

#### models.py

```
from photos.tasks import photo_download

class Photo(models.Model):
    ....fields....


@receiver(post_save)
def download_photo_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    photo = kwargs["instance"]
    result = photo_download.delay(photo.uid)
```

#### tasks.py

```
from photo.models import Photo

@task()
def photo_download(photo_uid, callback=None):
    ...do stuff...
    photo.status = 'D'
    photo.save()
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the model primary key as one of the arguments to the `run` method of your task and updating your Model as the last line in the `run` method?

Comment: I tried passing the primary key in.  But then in my `tasks.py` file I couldn't `from photo.models import Photo`

Comment: Are all your workers on the same machine or not?

Comment: Probably a circular dependency... Are you trying to create tasks from your models file?

Comment: oh goodness... it is the same machine now.  But in the future it will be different machines

Comment: What is the right thing to do when it is on the same machine?  What is the right thing to do when it is on different machines?

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work for you. I do the exact same thing for my project. i.e. pass the primary key and update the db table in a celery task and works fine. May be as @sdolan suggested, it could be a circular import issue.

Comment: yeah... I am creating tasks from my model file.  Is that bad?  I am using a `post_save` signal to create a celery task

Comment: @AlexisK That's not bad, but why do you need this line `from photo.models import Photo` if your tasks are inside models?

Comment: my tasks are in a `tasks.py` file.  I'll update the original questions with a layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing a circular import.  Your `tasks.py` file is importing your `models.py` file and vice-versa.  You should move your signals to a separate `signals.py` file to avoid it.

Comment: where should the `signals.py` file go?  In the app or in the project?  What should then import the `signals.py` file?

Comment: The naive way to break it out, you'd have models import signals which would import tasks which would import models, still giving you a circular import.  What's a reliable way to register signal handlers if not directly by the model?  Or how else would you break the (3-way instead of 2-way) circular import?

Comment: Further investigation yielded [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11483929/2246212) of a project structure to avoid circular imports for model-dependent tasks triggered by model signals.  Also note the comment about passing in a `dispatch_uid` argument to prevent duplicate signals.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in documentation:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#example

See spam_filter task:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#blog-tasks-py

Comment: Sure it does, ``spam_filter`` task in documentation example updates comment instance when task is finished and that was the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have the other side [read your Django settings](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) so that it can update the model easily.

Comment: this looks good.  Is there a more detailed guide on setting up celery to be able to modify the dispatchers database?

Comment: Once you've loaded the settings you can import from the project and manipulate it just as you would *within* the project (provided `sys.path` is modified appropriately).