# Django 1.2: How to connect pre_save signal to class method

Tags: python, django, signals, python-2.7, django-1.2

I am trying to define a "before_save" method in certain classes in my django 1.2 project.  I'm having trouble connecting the signal to the class method in models.py.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    ....
    def before_save(self, sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        self.test_field = "It worked"
```

I've tried putting pre_save.connect(before_save, sender='self') in 'MyClass' itself, but nothing happens.

I've also tried putting it at the bottom of the models.py file:

```
pre_save.connect(MyClass.before_save, sender=MyClass)
```

I read about connecting signals to class methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719038/where-should-signal-handlers-live-in-a-django-project), but can't figure out the code.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather than use a method on MyClass, you should just use a function. Something like:

```
def before_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.test_field = "It worked"

pre_save.connect(before_save, sender=MyClass)
```

Comment: Please don't recommend this. The reason for using a class method is that it keeps the code much cleaner and better organized, especially if the method only relates to the class and its data.

Comment: If the method only relates to the class and its data, I think it's better to over ride save method instead.

Answer (score 9):

A working example with *classmethod*:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    #....
    @classmethod
    def before_save(cls, sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        instance.test_field = "It worked"

pre_save.connect(MyClass.before_save, sender=MyClass)
```

There's also a great decorator to handle signal connections automatically: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2124/

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I was looking for an answer to this earlier today so why not. It seems from your code that you actually wanted to use an instance method (from the `self` and the field assignment). DataGreed addressed how to use it for a class method, and using signals with instance methods is pretty similar.

```
class MyClass(models.Model)

    test_field = models.Charfield(max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        pre_save.connect(self.before_save, sender=MyClass)

    def before_save(self, sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        self.test_field = "It worked"
```

I'm not sure if this is a good idea or not, but it was helpful when I needed an instance method called on an object of class A before save from class B.