# Django OneToOneField and signals

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have a model called `DeviceStatus` which has a `OneToOne` relationship with another model called `Device`. I want to get the `id` passed to the `DeviceStatus` object before saving, but all I get is a `ForwardManyToOneDescriptor` object.

```
class DeviceStatus(TimeStampedModel):
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device)
    # other fields

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.device)

    def copy_to_archive(**kwargs):
        print DeviceStatus.device

    pre_save.connect(copy_to_archive)
```

Can somebody guide me through how to get the Device id being passed? TIA

Comment: If you want to use class method as signal handler read http://stackoverflow.com/a/11647745/3627387

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev hey this worked! Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped)) updated my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be instance method

```
def copy_to_archive(self, **kwargs):
    print self.device
```

Also connecting signal like this won't work. But this is different question.

Answering comment and extending my answer in comment to post

This what needed to be done

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    #....
    @classmethod
    def before_save(cls, sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        instance.test_field = "It worked"

pre_save.connect(MyClass.before_save, sender=MyClass)
```

[Django 1.2: How to connect pre_save signal to class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904799/django-1-2-how-to-connect-pre-save-signal-to-class-method/11647745#11647745)

Comment: it won't allow me to pass `self` here

Comment: @VenuSaini who won't? Does your signal get called?

Comment: if i try to pass `self` like you did, the signal wants me to pass something corresponding to that in `pre_save.connect(copy_to_archive)`

Comment: yes the signal does get called. I'm just not able to figure out how to get the id of the selected `Device`