# Django signals doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-signals

My *models.py*:>

```
class Aval(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
    salao = models.ForeignKey(Salao)
    rate = models.IntegerField(choices=RATE, default=5)
    criacao = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True)
    comentario = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    aprovado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My *signals.py*:>

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Aval)
def new_rate(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    aval = instance

    print("Aval is saved.")
```

I'm testing the signal post_save for Aval model, When I'm save some object Aval it not printing "Aval is saved" . What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22924754/594589

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should signal handlers live in a django project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719038/where-should-signal-handlers-live-in-a-django-project)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Original answer for Django < 1.7:**

You should include:

```
import signals
```

to `__init__.py` file of your application.

**Edit: Django >= 1.7:**

Signals can be registered in `django.apps.AppConfig.ready`  as described in Signals [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver) and `AppConfig` [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)

> Where should this code live?
>
> Strictly speaking, signal handling and registration code can live
> anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to avoid the
> application’s root module and its models module to minimize
> side-effects of importing code.
>
> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
> submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are
> connected in the ready() method of your application configuration
> class. If you’re using the receiver() decorator, import the signals
> submodule inside ready().

Comment: Thank you wolendranh, it works! Why it's not in django doc ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/

Comment: @rayashi not sure about that)

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if the paste is wrong, but in that code your model is named Avaliacao and not Aval, The Model and the sender argument has to match

Comment: Sorry Krs you rigth. :(