# Assign default group to new user Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to assign a group to every new user registered into the system. I've already read something about it in another questions but I don't really know where to add the necessary code to make it work.
I'm using Django 2.1.3 and I'm logging users using allauth (social login, but it shouldn't make any difference as a new instance in the User table is created)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `@post_save` signal for example that, each time a `User` is created, adds the given group to the groups of the `User`. Typically signals reside in a file named `handlers.py` in the `signals` directory of an `app`, so you probably should create or modify the files listed in boldface:

```
app/
    signals/
        __init__.py
        handlers.py
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    ...
```

```
# app/signals/handlers.py

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        g1 = Group.objects.get(name='group_name')
        instance.groups.add(g1)
```

where `group_name` is the name of the group you want to add.

You should then import the `handlers.py` module in your `MyAppConfig` (create one if you do not have constructed such config yet):

```
# app/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app'
    verbose_name = "My app"

    def ready(self):
        import app.signals.handlers
```

and register the `MyAppConfig` in the `__init__.py` of the `app`:

```
# app/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'app.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Comment: As per usual :) just a comprehensive, solid and pretty answer. You might add the `created` check though to avoid some unnecessary work.

Comment: The docs recommend using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of `django.contrib.auth.models.User` for signals. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Comment: @HåkenLid That is especially true if you want your app to be reusable in other projects that might have a custom user model. Otherwise you cn just use the the user model directly. You can also use the `get_user_model()` function.

Comment: @HåkenLid: yes, but I was not yet sure if `post_save` was a `ModelSignal`, since if it is not, it can not really handle a `str`ing as `sender`. But indeed, it can.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i'm having the same problem, i liked your solution and i want to implement it, but in my case, i'm using table inheritance, and i want to assign a user to a group according to the user type.
so if the user is an agent, he will be assigned to 'agents' group, and so on.
how could I implement that?

Answer (score 3):

If this should happen for any new `User` instance, you can connect a handler to the `post_save` signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def handle_new_job(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        user = kwargs.get('instance')
        g = Group.objects.get(name='whatever')
        user.groups.add(g)
```

Include this code in your app and make sure it is imported as stated e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719038/where-should-signal-handlers-live-in-a-django-project).

Comment: Also a well-explained, compact answer, so +1 :)

Comment: Shouldn't this happen when `created == True`?

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes, and it does. I just provided `False` as a default value to the `dict.get` method to make it more robust for the case when `created` might for some reason be missing from the `kwargs`. You can change that to `True` to err on the side of adding the group to an already existing rather than missing out on adding it to a new one.

Comment: I misread that as `kwargs.get('created') == False`. That said, I believe the instance and created arguments are always passed to post_save signal handlers.

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes, it should always be present. This is just a coding habit of mine. Be as explicit as possible and assume gappy knowledge of your colleagues :)