# Where should i put Django Signals?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

Hey I apologize in advance for my English.

I use Django Signal in my models.py to delete user images from my media directory. Everything works great but in Django documentation I have found something like this:

> Where should this code live?
>
> Strictly speaking, signal handling and registration code can live
> anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to avoid the
> application’s root module and its models module to minimize
> side-effects of importing code.
>
> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
> submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are
> connected in the ready() method of your application configuration
> class. If you’re using the receiver() decorator, import the signals
> submodule inside ready().

Soo my questions is where and how I should properly use Django signals and what kind of consequences may be if I still used Singals In my models.py

I also have found this topic:
[Where should signal handlers live in a django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719038/where-should-signal-handlers-live-in-a-django-project)
but it was for django 1.7 and may be a little out dated.

Comment: There are no consequences. Most projects simply define this in `signals.py` and load it in the app config, but that is more *conventional*.

Comment: That being said, one should be careful with signals, a lot of Django ORM calls, especially the ones that do processing in bulk circumvent the signals.

Comment: Ok so to be clearly. My signals will be work properly but best practice in Django say that I should put my signals into signals.py and load it in the app config. Am I right?

Comment: indeed, that's correct.